# Restful Web API from Browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 WEB API to create a Restful API service. This is my first go at it, so if you feel I am taking a wrong approach please feel free to correct.

I want to create a rest API (only & not a website, the consumer of the api can decide where they want to consume it), in the past I have used Restful WCF service to achieve this.

I have created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application and chose the WebAPI project template. I have added a controller class 'CatalogueController.cs' the purpose is on Get() operation I want to return the Catalogue list. The CatalogueDo contains only one property 'Service'  of type string.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet()]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Catalogue);
    }
```

When I run the application the browser loads with the URL `http://localhost:5502/` resource not found, if I add the controller name  `http://localhost:5502/Catalogue/` the browser pops open a notepad with,

```
[{"Service":"Exchange"},{"Service":"Holidays"}]
```

The data is correct but
the browser keeps showing resource not found and after my request has been served the URL changes to `http://localhost:5502/`.

Question,

- Am I doing something wrong? Should the response that pops up in the
  notepad not be shown as xml in the browser it self?
- Why does the controller name get removed from the URL once the request has been served?
- Is it at all possible to invoke this REST service from Excel or Power Pivot?

Comment: I changed your title since the question does not involve Excel.

Comment: @TarunArora Try using `Fiddler`(debugging tool) to debug your service url. The default format or content type is `Json`, so you are supposed to receive Json as the return type unless otherwise specified. Usually, the default Url is this `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"`- which implies that if you enter the `controller` name after the `http://localhost:xxxx/api/{Controller}`   you will be served with a list/collection of objects incase if you have got a default `GET` request and an optional `id` parameter fetches you an object with that particular `id`..

Comment: ....like `http://localhost:xxxx/api/Catalogue/14` gives you data of catalogue with id=14.